# Managing a private cocoapod with the same name of a public cocoapod

Tags: ios, cocoapods, podspec

We have a private spec repo. One of our private pods has a dependency to another internal pod called CWFoundation (`s.dependency 'CWFoundation', '~> 0.0.1'`). The podspec of CWFoundation is only a way of using CWFoundation from jayway (https://github.com/jayway/CWFoundation) as a pod (as it doesn't exist podspec file for it).

Everything was working fine until someone else created a new project in github with the same name, CWFoundation (https://github.com/guojiubo/CWFoundation) and added it to the public repo of cocoapods.

Now our internal pod, when resolves the dependencies, instead of downloading CWFoundation from our private spec repo, downloads the one from the public repo and nothing works.

I read at cocoapods.org that

> If you plan on forking a library that is already part of the Master Spec repo, for now we suggest choosing a name that starts with a letter before M

But we're following this rule, the pod is called CWFoundation and starts with 'C' and it doesn't work.

What can I do to retrieve our private podspec file for CWFoundation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This comment of 'a letter before M' is referring to the name of your private specs repo in `~/.cocoapods/repos`. Since `~/.cocoapods/repos/master` is the default you want something like `~/.cocoapods/repos/alpha` as opposed to `~/.cocoapods/repos/zeta`. As long as this is true it should use the first spec that it finds which will be yours before the one in the master specs repo.

**EDIT**

Based on the comments to my answer this looks like a bug in CocoaPods. Please [submit an issue](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/new). In the meantime, just renaming your podspec will fix the issue.

Comment: Our private specs repo is called GG-CocoaPods-Specs. So, it should work, right?

Comment: Our private specs repo is called GG-CocoaPods-Specs in ~/.cocoapods/repos. I've tried changing the repo name to gg-CocoaPods-Specs, just in case lowercase/uppercase matters, but I got the same. I do pod install and I still get CWFoundation (0.0.4), the incorrect one...

Comment: What's the rest of your folder structure look like?

Comment: Do you want to see the whole structure of ~/.cocoapods/repos,  the structure of GG-CocoaPods-Specs or the one of master? Or all? Thanks Keith!

Comment: The structure of your private specs repo.

Comment: I was thinking one thing. Is it possible that we are retrieving 0.0.4 for the public repository because we have 'CWFoundation', '~> 0.0.1' in the podspec file and the higher version of both pod spec repositories is 0.0.4 from the public one?

Comment: The structure of the related internal pods: ./CWCoreData:
0.0.1

./CWCoreData/0.0.1:
CWCoreData.podspec

./CWFoundation:
0.0.1

./CWFoundation/0.0.1:
CWFoundation.podspec

Comment: I'm not sure there is an issue. I've modified the internal podspec with the CWFoundation dependency to 'CWFoundation', '0.0.1' (removed ~) and now it works. I understand that with ~ looks for the biggest version in both repos. And if we use a fixed version takes the one of the "first" alphabetical repo. Am I right?

Comment: Yea that's right. The bug here is ignoring that when you use `~>`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

`pod "NameConflictedPod", :source => MY_OWN_SPEC_REPOSITORY, :tag => '0.1'`

That works for me.

`MY_OWN_SPEC_REPOSITORY` is the git URL for your private specs repo. As we know the official default specs repo is `https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git`.

Hope I described `MY_OWN_SPEC_REPOSITORY` well.

Warning: This solution specifies the version of the pod. It cannot use version like '~> 0.0.1' which automatically update minor bug fixed version. But...It's kind of not a big deal as the pod is developed by yourself :P

Answer (score 0):

For me, it worked after doing like below.

```
source 'https://github.com/steve-ham/MySpecs.git'
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

target 'MyProject' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for MyProject
  pod 'MyLibrary', :git => 'https://github.com/steve-ham/MyLibrary'
end
```